# Unexpected behavior while extracting files from the command prompt

Tags: java, deployment, zip, swt, jface

Hi all i am working on a installation wizard for my application in which i am using command line unzip utility for extracting application specific files in the target directory selected by user. For creating the installation wizard i have used JFace wizard and when user clicks on the finish button of the wizard i am executing following command to extract files from a zip file

```
            runTime.exec( "unzip" + SWT.SPACE + "master.zip" + SWT.SPACE + "-d"  +  SWT.SPACE + "\"" + installationDirectory + "\"");
```

This command line works fine and all the files are getting extracted.
But i also want to show user a message dialog saying that the application is successfully installed. Following is the main method that i am using to execute the wizard.

```
           public void run() throws PropertiesNotFoundException {

    display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.TITLE 
            | SWT.BORDER | SWT.MIN);
    try {

        WizardDialog dlg = new  WizardDialog(shell, new InstallationWizard());
        dlg.open();

    } catch (Exception e){
        MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error", e.getMessage());

    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws PropertiesNotFoundException {         
    new LaunchWizard().run();

    if(DataBean.getInstance().isFinishPressed()){
        MessageDialog.openInformation(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), "Success", "The QTL is successfully installed.");

    }

}
```

The issue is that when i press on finish button of wizard and the success message dialog appears , unless that message dialog box is not closed all the files are not getting extracted. I am launching this application through the eclipse ide and unless the application is exited the files are not getting extracted properly, if instead of closing message dialog box if i manually terminate the application from eclipse the files are getting extracted. Any help on this.
Thanks

Comment: *"installation wizard for my application"*  If the app. has a GUI, the solution for an installer/updater for Windows, *nix & OS X is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It is supplied free with the JRE & has many features (see link for details).

Comment: *"..executing following command to extract files from a zip file

            `runTime.exec( "unzip"..`"*  That is a very platform specific way to unzip files.  Use the J2SE based [ZIP API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thank you for replying, as you have mentioned about the Java Web start, but its not the installation wizard that i am looking for, neither the problem is associated with it. The issue is that once the i execute the unzip command unless the application is terminated the files are not getting extracted properly.